# sed and regular expressions

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

So I made this regular epression that works well with egrep and it gets the job done:

```
egrep "(^|[ ]+)([^ ]+)([ ]+)\2([ ]+|$)" $1
```

I tried working with it on sed but for some reason its not working.

```
sed '/\(^|[ ]\+\)\([^ ]\+\)\([ ]\+\)\2\([ ]\+|$\)/!d' $1
```

If someone could help me understand what is the problem with it and how can I use regular expressions like in egrep but with sed,or explain how sed works with backtracking?

Comment: Use `-r` (or `-E`) option to enable extended regex flavor.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `\|` in sed?

Answer (score 0):

The vertical bar (alternation) should also be escaped:

```
sed '/\(^|[ ]\+\)\([^ ]\+\)\([ ]\+\)\2\([ ]\+|$\)/!d' "$1"     # Yours.
sed '/\(^\|[ ]\+\)\([^ ]\+\)\([ ]\+\)\2\([ ]\+\|$\)/!d' "$1"   # correct.
```

But it is easier if you call for extended rexexp in sed:

```
sed -E '/(^|[ ]+)([^ ]+)([ ]+)\2([ ]+|$)/!d' "$1"
```

Comment: Worth noting is that `-r` is GNU sed, while `-E` works for BSD and GNU (undocumented)

Comment: The `vertical bar` is called an alternation.